# $mysqli->fetch_object($result) not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning mysqli.

I am trying to fetch data from a table "tbllogin".

```
      //DATABASE CONNECTION

      $hostname="p:localhost";
      $database="dbLogin";
      $username="user1";
      $password="pwd1";



      $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password,$database);

      if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

       echo mysqli_connect_error();

      }

      // Create Query
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tbllogin";


      // Escape Query

      $query = $mysqli->real_escape_string($query);
      echo $query;

      // Execute Query

      if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){

          print_r($result);

          while($row = $mysqli->fetch_object($result)){

              echo $row->column;

          }

          //Free result set
          $result->close();

      }



      ?>
```

But `$mysqli->fetch_object($result)` is not working. The `if` statement containing `$mysqli->fetch_object($result)` does not execute. I cannot identify if there is any error.

Please help.
Also, suggest whether mysqli procedural form is better or object-oriented form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove print_r() before while loop and try it

Comment: Is your query executing fine? what is the `print_r()` showing? Try losing the `p:` and just use `localhost`.

Comment: No. It does not work. The execution stops at the while loop

Comment: I removed the p: . The echo $query echos the select query "SELECT * FROM tbllogin" But the while loop is still not working.

Comment: print_r($result) gives this:- mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

Comment: Read the answers below, use `$result->fetch_object()` instead of `$mysqli->fetch_object()` ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `$result->fetch_object()` ?

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

From Example 1:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
    }
```

According to the answers on [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961782/mysqli-oo-or-procedural), there is not much of a difference between the two.

Comment: Thank you. This worked fine. Can you please suggest whether mysqli procedural form is better or object-oriented form (with respect to performance and speed) ?

Comment: The difference is negligible according to the answers on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961782/mysqli-oo-or-procedural

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){

      print_r($result);

      while($row = $result->fetch_object($result)){

       //do something

      }
 }
```

You need to chain the commands together.