# MYSQLi fetch object issue

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Why am I getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object()

Heres my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_data_hostname, $db_data_username, $db_data_password, $db_data_dbname);
    $query = "SELECT attName, attType, attOptions FROM form_constructor WHERE  device_name='$deviceType';";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $mysqli->fetch_object($result)){

        echo $row->attName;
        echo $row->attType;         
        echo $row->attOptions;

    }
```

Comment: Your syntax is off, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209719/mysqli-fetch-objectresult-not-working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the mysqli result:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

        echo $row->attName;
        echo $row->attType;         
        echo $row->attOptions;

    }
```

Comment: I now get this error: Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Comment: Sure..remove the parameter..my bad.

Answer (score 4):

**Why are you getting the error?**

You need to use the variable `$result` which has `$mysqli->query` assigned to it. [Read about MySQLi Object approach on the manual](http://php.net/mysqli)

**Your code, fixed.**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_data_hostname, $db_data_username, $db_data_password, $db_data_dbname);
    $query = "SELECT attName, attType, attOptions FROM form_constructor WHERE  device_name='$deviceType';";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){

        echo $row->attName;
        echo $row->attType;         
        echo $row->attOptions;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call fetch_object on the stmt result you get from $result.
So your while loop would look like:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
```